# Compiler error but program executes fine

Tags: java

I am confused with below code, Eclipse shows compiler error as "This static method cannot hide the instance method from Super" but when executed it works fine.

```
package com.journaldev.java;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super s = new Subclass();
        s.foo();
    }
}

class Super {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
}

class Subclass extends Super {
    static void foo() {
        System.out.println("Subclass");
    }

}
```

See the output in below image, can someone clarify this?

[image: Why Program Runs even though Compiler Error?]

Comment: Are you sure you're not just executing a previously compiled version? Generally speaking, if it can't be compiled then it can't be run... (by the default JDK toolkit at least, I've no idea if Eclipse is doing some trickery under the hood.)

Comment: may be some good info in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256005/why-static-method-cannot-hide-instance-method-in-java/33256605#33256605

Comment: Open up the `Subclass.class` file and see if there is a static method with that name. I bet there's not.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov if `Subclass.class` extends `Super.class`, wouldn't the method inside `Super.class` with the same name also need to be static?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I don't quite understand your statement is what I mean. In `Subclass.class` there is already a static method with that name. The static is missing from `Super.class` I believe

Comment: @IsThisJavascript, no, it doesn't need to be exactly static or instance. They should match though: either the two are static or the two are instance methods.

Comment: It turns out to be some magic done by Eclipse, program throws proper error in Command Line. However Eclipse change the Subclass foo() method implementation to throw Error as "static void foo()
  {
    throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tThis static method cannot hide the instance method from Super\n");
  }" and then compiles it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse allows you to run "most" of your code even when it won't all compile properly - although it usually prompts you. Typically the code that doesn't compile just throws an exception to indicate that compilation failed.

In this case, you never end up calling `Subclass.foo`, so you don't see the compilation error exception.

If you change the first line of `main` to:

```
Subclass s = new Subclass();
```

... then it *will* attempt to call the broken method, and you'll get output like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This static method cannot hide the instance method from Super

    at sandbox.Subclass.foo(Test.java:18)
    at sandbox.Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

Personally I would *strongly* advise you to hit "Cancel" when you try to run something and Eclipse tells you there's a compile-time error with it. If you've previously clicked on "Always launch without asking" you need to go into your preferences and under "Launching" change "Continue launch if project contains errors" from "Always" to "Prompt". (The text may have changed; I'm using a fairly old version of Eclipse.)

Comment: You are right, when I run the program using Command Line, it throws error as runtime too because there is no Subclass.class file. But in Eclipse, it changes the foo() method implementation to throw error as "    throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tThis static method cannot hide the instance method from Super\n");"